# How many electrons does it take to switch on a transistor

Tags: electromagnetism, cpu

How many electrons does it take to switch on a transistor, I read somewhere that Inel had made some electrical "paths" so small that they can allow only individual electrons to flow at a time, or something like that.

So is one electron enough to switch on a transistor and is there any theory or school of thought on how the number of electrons flowing through circuits relates to the speed of say CPUS/GPUS.

Comment: "Is there any theory .. relating to the speed": the short answer is yes, but it's a large and complex subject!

Comment: There's even research into [single-electron transistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-electron_transistor).

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes little sense.  You haven't even specified the type of transistor.

For bipolar transistors, it is *current*, not charge (electrons or holes), that turn on the transistor.  A small charge thru the base will allow a larger charge to flow thru the collector, but this is a one-time thing and wouldn't make the transistor be "on", whatever that is really supposed to mean.

MOSFETs are different in that they do work on charges.  However, there you can answer the question yourself by looking at a datasheet.  The gate to source looks like a capacitor to the circuit driving the gate.  A finite amount of charge (some number of electrons) sloshed onto or off of the gate will therefore change its voltage some finite amount.  Take the gate voltage difference between whatever you consider the transistor to be on and off at, multiply that by the effective gate capacitance, and you have the charge it takes to switch the transistor between on and off.

For example, let's say you have a small FET that requires 3V gate swing between on and off, and that its effective gate capacitance is 1 nF (just making up numbers, see datasheet for real values).  (3 V)(1 nF) = 3 nC.  There are about 6.24x10<sup>18</sup> electrons per Coulomb, so that represents about 19x10<sup>9</sup> electrons.

Comment: +1. Also, a [BC547](http://arduino.cc/documents/datasheets/BC547.pdf) bipolar transistor could be in saturation ("on") at Ib = 0.5 mA. That is about 3,120,000,000,000,000 electrons passing some point on the BC547's base lead every second.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of electrons required to turn on a discrete MOSFET from the *gate charge* datasheet numbers. It is not a small number.

For example, looking at figure 10 of the 2N7002 [datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/2N/2N7000.pdf) we can see that 0.8nC is about enough. The charge of an electron is \$1.6\times 10^{-19}\$ C, so it takes ~\$4 \times 10^9\$ electrons.

If you're interested in physics experiments, you can look into SETs ( [Single Electron Transistors](http://faculty.uml.edu/jtherrien/Classes/QE/Files/Final_Set_1.ppt) ).

[image]